# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/internal/jackson/jaxrs/cfg/ObjectWriterModifier

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am trying to run a enterprise project,It is developed using Spring Boot,I am getting the below stacktrace.
I just want to run the project in IntelliJ,How can I just make it run,I tried adding the jars manually to Dependencies in Intellij,Still I get NoClassDefError.How can I go about debugging this error in this large application?

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled." traceId="" spanId="" parentSpanId="" exportable=""
2020-12-10 12.44.32.814 severity="ERROR" threadname="main" class="o.s.b.SpringApplication" message="Application startup failed" traceId="" spanId="" parentSpanId="" exportable=""
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonFieldFilter': Failed to introspect bean class [com.vue.rest.service.interceptor.JacksonFieldFilter] for lookup method metadata: could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/internal/jackson/jaxrs/cfg/ObjectWriterModifier
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1091)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.test.test.config.Application.main(Application.java:62)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/internal/jackson/jaxrs/cfg/ObjectWriterModifier
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/internal/jackson/jaxrs/cfg/ObjectWriterModifier
```

My classpath

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this dependency in your POM file

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Parth I have a Gradle Project I tried adding the jar mentioned to the classpath still the same error.I did decompile and see the classes the package structure is also different.

Answer (score 0):

Added the below dependency in dependencies.gradle and it worked fine

```
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.31'
```